# Can I use e text editor with an existing ruby installation?

Tags: windows, ruby, e-texteditor

I'm using windows and e text editor. I installed cygwin along with the e text editor as it prompted me too, but running ruby programs produces no errors and no output. I'd like to use an existing ruby installation instead, as I use ruby devkit and a number of gems I have already installed. Can I do that?